# Can not reindex the dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

## reindex the order of columns

```
columnsTitles = (['Fips','State', 'County', 'Precincts', 'Votes', 'White',
       'Black', 'Hispanic', 'Asian', 'Amerindian', 'Other','Total Population',
       'Less Than High School Diploma', 'At Least High School Diploma',
       '(At Least Bachelors's Degree)', 'Graduate Degree', 'School Enrollment',
       'Median Earnings 2010', 'Children Under 6 Living in Poverty',
       'Adults 65 and Older Living in Poverty',
       'Preschool.Enrollment.Ratio.enrolled.ages.3.and.4',
       'Poverty.Rate.below.federal.poverty.threshold', 'Gini.Coefficient',
       'Child.Poverty.living.in.families.below.the.poverty.line',
       'Management.professional.and.related.occupations',
       'Service.occupations', 'Sales.and.office.occupations',
       'Farming.fishing.and.forestry.occupations',
       'Construction.extraction.maintenance.and.repair.occupations',
       'Production.transportation.and.material.moving.occupations',
       'SIRE_homogeneity', 'median_age', 'Low.birthweight', 'Teen.births',
       'Children.in.single.parent.households', 'Adult.smoking',
       'Adult.obesity', 'Diabetes', 'Sexually.transmitted.infections',
       'HIV.prevalence.rate', 'Uninsured', 'Unemployment', 'Violent.crime',
       'Homicide.rate', 'Injury.deaths', 'Infant.mortality'])
df_data.reindex(columns=columnsTitles)
```

> File "", line 5
>       '(At Least Bachelors's Degree)', 'Graduate Degree', 'School Enrollment',
>                            ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Any idea how I can fix this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

edit: sorry i didnt pay enough attention:
there is some qote to discard in your code, try to put "\" before single quotes in your strings.

```
    '(At Least Bachelors\'s Degree)'
```